# Django: How to annotate query set with count number of active users and non active users

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm wondering if there's a way to add two columns to Django admin display list with count of active users and count of non active users, something like this:

```
class UserAdmin(django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('name', 'num_active_user', 'num_non_active_user', )

def num_users(self, obj):
    return obj.num_users
num_users.short_description = "Number Of Users"
num_users.admin_order_field = 'num_users'

def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(UserAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    return qs.annotate(num_users=Count('user', distinct=True))
```

Is there a way to add condition in this line like this:

```
return qs.annotate(num_users=Count('user__is_active=True', distinct=True))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by using the following trick:

```
return qs.annotate(nnum_active_users=django.db.models.Count(django.db.models.Case(django.db.models.When(
                                                                                            user__is_active=True, then=1, ))
                                                                      )
                           )
```